# Third-party libraries in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a standalone script for Google Sheets. I use third-party libraries like Bootstrap, moment.js and a few others. I use modal dialog to show content.

At the initial stage of development I was using CDN to get them from the net. However, before publishing the script I realized that it depends on the external resources and if there something has been changed it will stop working.

I know that Google provides reliable source of [Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) I use jQuery from it. However, the others I use are not present there.

At this point I came up with approach to add the minified content into separate *.html files. For example

```
 bootstrap.min.js.html -> <script type="text/javascript"> MINIFIED BOOTSTRAP </script>
```

Then include it to my main pages

```
<?!= methodToInclude('bootstrap.min.js'); ?>
```

It works, however the script significantly decreased in performance when the main page is loaded and it gives not good UX.

Are there any other reliable approaches to include the third-party libraries in your script project?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863416/can-bootstrap-js-be-used-in-gas-google-apps-script/28820528#28820528

Comment: @AndrewRoberts Thanks, but this exactly the same approach I used in the first place. I don't want my script to be dependent on external resources other than Google recommends them. The purpose of my question is how to don't do as is described in the answer you provided but still use third-party libraries.

Comment: The only other option might be to load less static content.  You can't inject JavaScript after the initial load, so that can't be delayed or added later.  I'm assuming that the load time has increased a lot?  I don't think you need to worry about using Bootstrap as an external dependency.  That's probably not going to become obsolete or abandoned any time soon.  If you have a lot of settings or user content being looked up, you could delay that until the user asks for it.  You can load some very small amount of content at first and then run an async call to immediately get more content on load

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to your methodToInclude() introduces it's own delay of up to a second or two. Instead of using one call for each library, try refactoring to use a single call for all your libraries, which should be about the same speed as a call to get a single library.

EG:   `<?!= includeJSLibraries(); ?>`

Returning:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> MINIFIED BOOTSTRAP </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"> MINIFIED MOMENT </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"> MINIFIED ETC. </script>
```

Note I haven't used this solution personally since I don't use many JS libraries in my interfaces, and when I do they are usually available Google Hosted.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this approach could increase performance for a little bit. However, I didn't exactly followed the exact approach. Instead, I created `includeJSLibraries()` which takes an array of file names, then loop through them and append their content. That allowed me to do `<?!= includeJSLibraries(['bootstrap.min.js', 'moment.js', 'etc.js']); ?>` on the *.html pages. In my case it increased response in average from 6 sec to 4 sec.